# Disabling all warnings during a Headless PDE build

Tags: eclipse-pde, pde

How do you disable all compiler warnings from headless PDE builds of Eclipse plugins?

I know I can do something like this in the build.properties:

```
javacWarnings..=-deadCode
```

To disable specific warnings by ID, but the [documentation is not very explicit](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_compiler_options.htm).

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I disable all warnings not just specific ones?
2. Can this be placed in the build.properties for the entire build, or must this be placed in the build.properties for each plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is thisL in the build.properties file of every plugin project, add the line:

```
compilerArg=-nowarn
```

It does not seem to work if I put that line in the build.properties of a feature or the build as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Setting "compilerArg=-warn:none" works for me (in the central build.properties file, not in each plugin)